# ArcGIS 9.3.1 User Privileges

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, arccatalog

I know that you can grant privileges for users using `ArcCatalog` for the whole `Dataset` as letting them select, update, delete and insert feature classes. But my question is how could I grant the privileges for each feature class in the `Dataset` for users.

Example :

```
Users     Feature Class
_____     _____________
 1             Ftr 1
 2             Ftr 2
```

User 1 can read and edit on Ftr1 but can only read Ftr2, and User 2 can read and edit on Ftr2 but can only read Ftr1. While Ftr1 and Ftr2 are within the same `Dataset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for this question in this link which can help a lot, I finally find it after a deep research http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/25830

But if there is any other answer, please tell me about it to correct this post and know the right information about it.

> **Question**
>
> Can different privileges be granted to feature classes within a
>   feature dataset?
>
> **Answer**
>
> All feature classes within a feature dataset must have the same
>   privileges. This is by design. Therefore, it is not possible to grant
>   different privileges to feature classes within a feature dataset.
>
> The role of a feature dataset is to group topologically-related
>   feature classes. Therefore, a user must have uniform privileges on all
>   feature classes in a dataset. For example, it would not make sense to
>   have edit privileges on a feature class of electrical lines but only
>   read privileges on the poles to which they are connected in a network.
>
> The feature dataset plays an important role in managing privileges. By
>   design, the feature dataset enforces that all feature classes it
>   contains share the same privileges; this is contingent on managing
>   privileges through ArcCatalog, which is required when working with a
>   geodatabase. For example, if in ArcCatalog a user right-clicks a
>   feature dataset and selects Privileges, ArcCatalog will automatically
>   grant privileges to all feature classes it contains. The converse is
>   true when revoking privileges from a dataset.